# how do i print 2 pages using vb.net without overlapping

Tags: vb.net, printing

Hi i have problem on printing output on vb.net, I run-out of ideas in my mind. I hope you can help me. Here's my code:

```
    If ComboBox1.Text = "Sampled" Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            If DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value = "True" Then
                Dim ContainerNo = DataGridView1.Item(18, i).Value
                Dim TotalContainer = DataGridView1.Item(19, i).Value

                'e.Graphics.DrawImage(image:=myBitmap2, point:=New Point(110, 40))
                e.Graphics.DrawString("SAMPLED", font3, Brushes.Black, 120, 70)
                e.Graphics.DrawString("CONTAINER No:________________OF________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 90, 140)
                e.Graphics.DrawString("REMARKS:_______________________________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 90, 160)
                e.Graphics.DrawString("SAMPLED BY:", font1, Brushes.Black, 170, 220)
                e.Graphics.DrawString("____________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 155, 235)
                e.Graphics.DrawString("QC SAMPLER/DATE", font1, Brushes.Black, 160, 250)

                e.Graphics.DrawString(ContainerNo, font1, Brushes.Black, 190, 138)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(TotalContainer, font1, Brushes.Black, 280, 138)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox12.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 160, 158)
                ' e.HasMorePages = True
                index += 1
                If index <= x Then
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                    MessageBox.Show("True")
                Else
                    e.HasMorePages = False
                    MessageBox.Show("false")
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

here's my current output now

[image]

I want my output to be like this

1st page: 2 of 3 (2 is based from Dim ContainerNo = DataGridView1.Item(18, i).Value) and (3
is from Dim TotalContainer = DataGridView1.Item(19, i).Value)

2nd page: 3 of 3

Sadly my current output now is containerNo:2 and containerNo:3 are overlapping each other on both pages, I hope you can help me

Comment: Why are you setting `HasMorePages` inside a loop? Go back to your previous question and study my answer. The code in the `PrintPage` event handler is to print ONE PAGE. You don't use a loop to print multiple pages in one call. Setting `HasMorePages` is the LAST thing you do, after you have printed your one page.

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't bother to actually run my example code and examine it in the debugger. You should do so. Set a breakpoint at the top of the `PrintPage` event handler and step through it to see what it does, then implement the same principle yourself. The basic steps are to determine what page you're printing, get the data for that page, print that data, then determine whether there are more pages to print. You're obviously not doing that if you have text for multiple pages printed on the same page.

Comment: thankyou for your answer. I tried to put e.hasmorepages below next just now. and the output still the same. 2 and 3 are still overlapping on both pages.

Comment: You can't just move a line of code if the rest of the code doesn't implement the correct logic. The code you have doesn't implement the steps I just specified. Instead of trying to fix the code you have, start again and actually implement the steps I specified and in the order I specified. Don't write any code to print anything until you have implemented the two steps before that.

Comment: sorry i cant understand the codes you sent before.. could you please reconstruct my code above to my desired output then i will try to understand it afterwards. please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the loop. This function can be called multiple times in a single print job (`HasMorePages` controls whether it will be called again). Each time it's called you **only print one page worth of data**.

```
Dim i As Integer = index
If ComboBox1.Text = "Sampled" AndAlso DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value = "True" Then
    Dim ContainerNo = DataGridView1.Item(18, i).Value
    Dim TotalContainer = DataGridView1.Item(19, i).Value

    e.Graphics.DrawString("SAMPLED", font3, Brushes.Black, 120, 70)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("CONTAINER No:________________OF________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 90, 140)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("REMARKS:_______________________________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 90, 160)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("SAMPLED BY:", font1, Brushes.Black, 170, 220)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("____________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 155, 235)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("QC SAMPLER/DATE", font1, Brushes.Black, 160, 250)

    e.Graphics.DrawString(ContainerNo, font1, Brushes.Black, 190, 138)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(TotalContainer, font1, Brushes.Black, 280, 138)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox12.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 160, 158)
End If
'Make sure index is declared OUTSIDE THE METHOD
index += 1        
e.HasMorePages = index <= DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
```

Comment: thankyou so much for your answer.. that was exact answer i was looking for :D